# <form> tags not supported by Sharepoint

Tags: java, php, html, css

I know that there are a few posts answered about this question but I still wasn't able to find a solution. So basically, I want to create a simple form where people on sharepoint who have questions can directly ask the question in an input box and whenever they press submit, it sends an email.

I know that form tags don't work. So far, this is the code I have

```
if($_POST["message"]) {


mail("exemple@intact.net", "Here is the subject line",


$_POST["insert your message here"]. "From: exemple@intact.net");

}

?>

  <form method="post" action="/questionsform.php">


     <textarea name="message"></textarea>


     <input type="submit">


  </form>
```

Then I'm really not quite sure what to do...

Comment: If it's SharePoint why are you trying to code with PHP? SharePoint has its own systems for programming it, using .net

Comment: Usually I create a html page and I add it to a webpart that's what I always do, what would you recommend doing?

Comment: Well if you need a backend then use .net rather than PHP was my thinking